# Supplying options to HSpec from Cabal

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, hspec

I'm trying to get started with hspec. I've got a working case working with QuickCheck, but I would just like some more detail when running `cabal test`. I found [this article](http://hspec.github.io/running-specs.html) from hspec, giving instructions on supplying some more detailed control when running the executable. I'm currently using `hi` to initialize my haskell packages, so my cabal test suite looks like this:

```
Test-Suite spec
  Type:                 exitcode-stdio-1.0
  Default-Language:     Haskell2010
  Hs-Source-Dirs:       src
                      , test
  Ghc-Options:          -Wall
  Main-Is:              Spec.hs
  Build-Depends:        base
                      , hspec
                      , QuickCheck
                      , quickcheck-instances
                      , mtl
                      , text
                      , transformers
```

My guess is something like "default command line arguments", but that just doesn't feel right. How could I supply arguments to a hspec suite?

Also, this might be important. `hi` splits the test suite so that the only content in `Spec.hs` is:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover #-}
```

but all tests and code reside in `test/MainSpec.hs`, which exports `main` and `spec`.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the **Using a custom main function** section on http://hspec.github.io/hspec-discover.html

Relevant bits copied here for your convenience:

> Here is an example that shows how this can be utilized to specify a
>   different default formatter:
>
> ```
> -- file test/Spec.hs
> {-# OPTIONS_GHC -F -pgmF hspec-discover -optF --module-name=Spec #-}
>
> -- file test/Main.hs
> module Main where
>
> import Test.Hspec.Runner
> import Test.Hspec.Formatters
> import qualified Spec
>
> main :: IO ()
> main = hspecWith defaultConfig {configFormatter = Just progress} Spec.spec
> ```